# How to Obtain Contents of HTML Element in CSS

Tags: html, css

Example - I have an element like this:

```
<div class='playerId'>1001</div>
```

And I want to style it with a background image whose URL is derived from the contents of the element itself (based on a naming convention):

```
.playerId  
{  
    background-image: url('/images/userAvatars/' + [INNERTEXT] + '.jpg');  
}
```

(I know this concatenation is not legal; it's pseudocode representing what I'm trying to do.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do this with scripting.  CSS cannot do it alone.

You could use jQuery to make it happen, something like

```
var a = $('.playerId').text();

$('.playerId').css('background-image','/images/userAvatars/' + a + '.jpg');
```

Sidenote: I would consider using IDs (`#`) instead of classes (`.`) for the elements if you wanted them to be unique.